# Diferencias en cuartiles con librerias pandas y statistics en python

Tags: python, pandas, estadística

Utilizando un mismo df de pandas en python obtengo diferentes resultados para q1 y q3.

En pandas:

```
q1 = df.quantile(0.25)
```

En statistics:

```
q1 = statistics.quantiles(df, n=4)
```

El valor en pandas de q1 es = 78.5, usando statistics es 78
Lo mismo ocurre para q3, donde en pandas q3 = 90.5 y usando statistics es 91.

El tamaño de la muestra es `n = 35`.

Al tratarse de datos no agrupados, entiendo que q1 será el valor de la posición `(n + 1) / 4 = 9`, que es igual a 78 en mi df. Sin embargo quisiera saber por qué obtengo 78.5 al usar pandas. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

No hay una forma única de calcular los cuantiles, basta ver la documentación de [`df.quantile()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html) dónde tienes hasta 5 formas distintas, ver el parámetro `interpolation`. En el caso de la función base [`statistics.quantiles()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.quantiles) tiene dos formas, ver el parámetro `method`.

Para unificar criterios, usa el método `"inclusive`" que debería ser consistente con la interpolación lineal de `pandas`:

```
statistics.quantiles(df, n = 4, method = "inclusive")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!